# Formie help: 413: Couldn’t save submission due to errors

Tags: plugin-formie

I have an file uploader element attached to my formie form, with a 100mb max file size and a max of 6 files to be uploaded.

I have tested it and it worked fine, but now when I try and upload 6 photos with a max file size of 26mb it I receive the error:

413: Couldn’t save submission due to errors.

Could anyone suggest what the issue may be? 413 suggests an error due to file size but I can't see  identify why this may be.

I am running Craft Pro 4.4.15 and Formie 2.0.42.

TIA

Comment: Other things to check are your php.ini file's `post_max_size` setting and Craft's https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/general.html#maxuploadfilesize